# How can I access components from a spatial list and create buffer (width =0) to fix invalid geometries in R?

Tags: shapefile, r, geometry, error, buffer

I'm creating some concentric buffers up to 70 km away (every 10 km) around polygons of a `SpatialPolygonDataFrame`.

## illustrative picture

[image]

I used this code to create the buffers:

```
#I created a numeric vector with the buffers widths that I need#
 
     buffering<-c(seq(10000, 70000, by=10000))  
   
 
     #I creted a vector of characters 

     buff_labs <- c(seq(1,10, by=1)) %>% paste0("ring", .,"km",US)
    
      #I associate the character vector with the numeric vector    
        
      names(buffering) <- buff_labs
      
      #cal my data  
      setwd("~/prodes/min")

        minas <- readOGR("minas.shp")           
       
        # this function generates a list with the seven buffers that I need (70km, 20km, 30km, 40km, 
          50km, 60km e 70km). 

        buffers <-mapply(FUN = rgeos::gBuffer,
                          width = buffering,
                          MoreArgs = list(spgeom =minas, byid=TRUE),
                          SIMPLIFY = FALSE,
                          USE.NAMES = TRUE,
                          )
```

Until here the code works very well for all my shapesfiles

But I only need the 10 km wide ring for each distance and I used this code to remove the buffers centroids:

```
        centers <- c(minas, buffers[1:(length(buffers)-1)])
       
        rings <-mapply(FUN = raster::erase,
                       x = buffers,
                       y = centers,
                       SIMPLIFY = FALSE,
                       USE.NAMES = TRUE)
```

This code works very well in seven of eight shapefiles that I have, but in one generates this error:

```
RError in RGEOSBinTopoFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, id, drop_lower_td, unaryUnion_if_byid_false, :
TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point -669458.50954959029 
2325717.8159672269 at -669458.50954959029 2325717.81596...
```

But, I found a possible solution.
After creating the buffers, I have to create a new buffer (width = 0), in each buffer, because this error is usually related to invalid geometries generated when I made the buffers.
But I don't know how to put that in my code because, when I crieating the buffers I generate a vectors list with seven components. And I need to modfy one by one with (width =0) to corect the geometries.

And now, I really don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution....
I'll post the code here, because if someone comes to have the same problem and doubts, here's the tip.

> After creating the buffers, into a `lapply function` insert the buffer width 0

```
buffers <-lapply(buffers, FUN=rgeos::gBuffer,
                     width=0,
                     byid=T)
```

> And do the same with the list of center vectors:

```
centers<-lapply(centers, FUN=rgeos::gBuffer,
                     width=0,
                     byid=T)
```

After inserting this complement in my code, as shown in my question, it was possible to remove the centroid using raster :: erase.